# Return defined number of unique values in separate columns all meeting same 'Where' Criteria

Tags: sql, subquery, partition, google-bigquery

We enter overrides based on a unique value from our tables (we have two columns with unique values for each transaction, so may or may not be primary key).

Sometimes we have to enter multiple overrides based on the same set of criteria, so it would be nice to be able to pull multiple unique values in one query that all meet the same criteria in the where clause as our system throws a warning if the same unique id is used for more than one override.

Say we have some customers that were under charged for three months and we need to enter a commission override for each of the three sales people that split the accounts for each month:

I've tried the following code, but the same value gets returned for each column:

```
select month, customer, product, sum(sales),
any_value(unique_id)unique_id1,
any_value(unique_id)unique_id2,
any_value(unique_id)unique_id3
from table 
where customer in (j,k,l) and product = m and year = o
group by 1,2,3;
```

This will give me a row for each month and customer, but the values in unique_id1, unique_id2 and unique_id3 are the same on each row.

I was able to use:

```
select month, customer, product, sum(sales),
string_agg(unique_id, "," LIMIT 3)
from table 
where customer in (j,k,l) and product = m and year = o
group by 1,2,3;
```

and split the unique_ids in a spreadsheet but I feel there has to be a better way to accomplish this directly in SQL.

I figure I could use a sub query and select column based on row 1,2,3, but I'm trying to eliminate the redundancy of including the same 'where' criteria in the sub query.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help your explanation.

Comment: `string_agg` is not a MySQL function AFAIK (it looks like Postgres).  What is your actual database?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm using BigQuery, I've updated the tags accordingly. I will try to put together a sample database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beow is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I think you second query was close enough to get to something like below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT month, customer, product, sales,
  arr[OFFSET(0)] unique_id1,
  arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] unique_id2,
  arr[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] unique_id3
FROM (
  SELECT month, customer, product, SUM(sales) sales,
    ARRAY_AGG(unique_id ORDER BY month DESC LIMIT 3) arr
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE customer IN ('j','k','l') AND product = 'm' AND year = 2019
  GROUP BY month, customer, product
)
```